# Move semantics with std::vector

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue, lvalue

I have a question concerning the move semantics in C++. See this example:

```
class Buck {
public:
    Buck(std::vector<int> param) : data{param} {}

    std::vector<int> data;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A{1,2,3,4,5};
    Buck b{std::move(A)};
    std::cout << A.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs 0, which means `A` has been moved into the `data` variable of `b`.

Now, the big question - why does this work?

From what I understand, `A` is moved into the parameter `param` of the `Buck` constructor (since I force it to be an rvalue with `std::move()`, and the move constructor in `std::vector` is called). `param` itself should be an lvalue within the constructor function. So how on earth can `data{param}` call the move constructor of `std::vector` if `param` is an lvalue?

Comment: `So how on earth can data{param} call the move constructor of std::vector if param is an lvalue?` It doesn't. `A` is moved into `param` but `param` is __not__ moved into `data`. It probably should, though.

Comment: `data{param}` is **not** calling the move constructor.  It's calling the copy constructor.  You are **moving** the vector into `param` and **then copying** it to `data`.  Note that you program manages three distinct vectors: `A`, `param`, and `data`.

Comment: *So how on earth can data{param} call the move constructor of std::vector if param is an lvalue?* It doesn't, it does a copy.  The move happens when you move `A` into `param`

Comment: I.e. your constructor should be `Buck(std::vector<int> param) : data{std::move(param)} {}` or even better `explicit Buck(std::vector<int> param) : data{std::move(param)} {}`

Comment: From what I understand this would also move the vector if it was called from an lvalue which I do not want. So I will have to implement a function for rvalue and lvalue parameter.

Comment: `From what I understand this would also move the vector if it was called from an lvalue which I do not want.` No it won't.

Comment: @user2276094 A lvalue is never moved unless it is wrapped with `std::move` or it is a function local object and it is being returned out of the function.

Comment: `Buck(std::vector<int> param) : data{std::move(param)} {}` would behave appropriately for both l-values and r-values.  I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`A` is moved into `param` and then `param` is copied into `data`. You can test this with:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Data{
    Data() {
        std::cout << "init\n";
    }

    Data(Data const&) {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
    }

    Data(Data&&) {
        std::cout << "move\n";
    }
};

struct Buck {
    Buck(Data param): data{param} {} // copy

    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Data a;               // init
    Buck b{std::move(a)}; // move
}
```

```
init
move
copy
```

If you want to make moves, you always need to explicitly cast to an `rvalue` (e.g. by `std::move`):

```cpp
struct Buck {
    Buck(Data param): data{std::move(param)} {} // move

    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Data a;               // init
    Buck b{std::move(a)}; // move
}
```

```
init
move
move
```

If you want a single move to the data member, you can take a reference in the constructor:

```cpp
struct Buck {
    Buck(Data&& param): data{std::move(param)} {} // move

    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Data a;               // init
    Buck b{std::move(a)}; // call-by-reference
}
```

```
init
move
```

---

**Note:** You still need the explicit `rvalue`-cast in the member initialization! If you don't us it, you will make a copy:

```cpp
struct Buck {
    Buck(Data&& param): data{param} {} // copy!!!

    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Data a;               // init
    Buck b{std::move(a)}; // call-by-reference
}
```

```
init
copy
```

`std::move(a)` it the same as `static_cast<Data&&>(a)`. When you use a variable of type `Data&&` it is handled as `Data&` until you explicitly cast it to `Data&&` in an expression. Declaring a variable as `Data&&` is only important for how to initialize it, not how to use it!

---

The call-by-value is usefull, if want a simple-to-implement support for copy and move:

```cpp
struct Buck {
    // param can be copied or moved, then it is moved to data
    Buck(Data param): data{std::move(param)} {}

    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Data a;               // init
    std::cout << "----\n";
    Buck b{a};            // copy
    std::cout << "----\n";
    Buck c{std::move(a)}; // move
}
```

```
init
----
copy
move
----
move
move
```

If you want max performance you can avoid the second move by implementing both, a copy and a move constructor:

```cpp
struct Buck {
    Buck(Data const& param): data{param} {}       // copy
    Buck(Data&& param): data{std::move(param)} {} // move

    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Data a;               // init
    std::cout << "----\n";
    Buck b{a};            // call-by-lvalue-reference
    std::cout << "----\n";
    Buck c{std::move(a)}; // call-by-rvalue-reference
}
```

```
init
----
copy
----
move
```